# elixir ecto - the right way to get an avarage score from a column

Tags: elixir, ecto

what is the right way to get an average number from a column?
i have this query:

```
q = from r in Review,
      where: r.module_id == ^module_id,
      where: r.delete == false,
      select: %{entries: r, stars: avg(r.stars)}

    r = Repo.all(q)
```

will always get this error:

> (grouping_error) column "r0.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
> be used in an aggregate function

what do that means and how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

One cannot select a result having different dimensions. What do you expect to get in `entries` when `avg` aggregates on different reviews?

Consider the following input:

```
| id | module_id | stars |
|----|-----------|-------| 
|  1 |     1     |   3   |
|  2 |     1     |   5   |
|  3 |     2     |   1   |
```

OK, for `module_id == 1`, `avg(stars)` would be `4`. But what should be `r` then?

That said, you should probably rethink the query itself.

```
q =
  from r in Review,
  where: r.delete == false,
  where: r.module_id == ^module_id,
  group: r.module_id,
  select: %{module: r.module_id, stars: avg(r.stars)}
```

or like, depending on your real need.